# CoffeScript'esque language for Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, compiler-construction, coffeescript, uos

Seeing what has been done for Java with [Xtend](http://www.eclipse.org/xtend/) and [Mirah](http://www.mirah.org) I can't help but think someone must be playing around with something similar for Objective-C or even C and C++ for that matter.

After some searching I've come up with nil. Is anyone aware of a CoffeeScript like Objective-C implementation?

Update:
Good input so far from the two that have submitted answers, however wouldn't it be superior (realizing that that's a little subjective) to have an intermediate language that compiled directly to Obj-C precisely as per how CoffeScript works?  Now, I'm not asking for CoffeeScript mind you, but rather some language that doesn't compile directly, but rather gives you a more readable top layer syntactically a la Xtend.

Comment: Objective-C people are actually pretty fond of their syntax, often. Leading to things such as http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-J

Comment: Yes @RussellMull - I'm quite familiar with Obj-J, however I, frankly, don't like the syntax of Obj-C personally.  Coming from a C background it takes some serious "getting use to" time to come over to the syntax.  I've known quite a few people from academia who really have griped and complained about how it feels to get started on Obj-C.  Several have shelved it due to this as they'd prefer to have less syntax to worry about... but yeah, I know what you mean about dyed-in-the-wool ObjC folks.

Comment: Hi, regarding the update comment about compiling to ObjC, Eero supports this now as well. See: [Eero to Objective-C translation (source-to-source)](https://github.com/eerolanguage/eero/wiki/Translator)

Comment: Heh, you get addicted to Obj-C syntax because it's "self-commenting" by design. The very long method names with named parameters means simply reading the method calls tells you exactly what the code is doing. (That was only possible to pull off because the very first Obj-c editor back 1989 was the first to integrate auto-complete.) Once you've spent years or months working with easily read code, it's hard to go back. Plus, you get all the LISP-like structure which is hard to go without. Still, it is definitely a steep learning curve.

Comment: Worth checking out is https://github.com/kmalakoff/SubjectiveScript.m which aims to make objc more script like using short macros for common things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This project](http://under-os.com) actually compiles Ruby -> native code in the end, thus making it possible to write iOS apps via Ruby.  It's called UnderOS (uOS - because it's all about "u" according to the author ;)) and is about the best solution I've found if you want to do iOS development with Ruby:
https://github.com/under-os/under-os

Example of building a calculate app:
http://vimeo.com/81919125

[image]

Answer (score 12):

Yes: [Eero](http://eerolanguage.org/), which provides a somewhat Python-like syntax for Objective-C, implemented using a modified version of [clang](http://clang.llvm.org).  (I haven't tried using it, though, so I can't comment on how useful it is!)

Comment: That's nice to see. I really like what's being done with Eero there. Thanks for sharing that.

Comment: With @andy-arvanitis's comment above, I have to say that this is looking more like the answer now: compiling to ObjC, Eero supports this now as well. See: [Eero to Objective-C translation (source-to-source)](https://github.com/eerolanguage/eero/wiki/Translator)

Answer (score 1):

[MacRuby](http://macruby.org/) and [RubyMotion](http://www.rubymotion.com/) let you code Mac and iOS applications (respectively) in pure Ruby. CoffeeScript is very Ruby-inspired, so if you enjoy that language, i think you'll feel at home with Ruby :)

Also, it is my understanding that both MacRuby and RubyMotion integrate nicely with the native environment;  they don't run on a separate Ruby VM on top of Mac/iOS, so there is no big performance penalty and the native things are not that far away. So in that sense i think they are more similar in sipirt to Mirah for the JVM than to JRuby or Jython for example.

Comment: Excellent +1 on RubyMotion. I'd not seen that previously.  I have been under the impression that MacRuby just hasn't grown as I thought it would / should.  I personally felt for the last couple of years that Apple could have made it a first class citizen and allowed for a full dev env within Xcode for Ruby iOS apps... I'm quite sad to not see it come to fruition as of yet.

Comment: @ylluminate well, given all the effort Apple does to promote native apps, Xcode as the only IDE and Obj-C as the only language (or maybe to demote other alternatives, i don't know... vendor-lock maybe?), i think it's natural that other languages/tools have a hard being adopted. I haven't done any iOS development myself, but having done some Android, it's quite the same thing with Java (fortunately, the JVM is becoming a more polyglot platform each day... so that's slowly changing for good =D). One RubyMotion feature that i wish i had in Android is the interactive REPL.

Comment: I think at this point MacRuby is either dead or at least on development hiatus. Check into it's current status before committing to it for projects.

Comment: @TechZen you might want to see the new answer I popped up here which I recently discovered.